# h5py.File function throws NameError for mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi, hdf5, h5py, mpi4py

I am using h5py with mpi4py. I am reading an h5 file with as `h5py.File(fname, 'w', driver='mpio', comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD)`  but I got an NameError.

I checked the source code from where the error comes and it needs `h5py.h5.get_config().mpi` to be True in order to import mpi4py. But it's set to False.
I have mpi4py installed and it works well.

The problems began when I updated numpy, I tried to go back to the previous version but it did'nt solve the problem. Before this update I had no problem with h5py

the full message error is :

```py
  File "main.py", line 87, in <module>
    memory = H5_memory(MEM_SIZE, STATE_SHAPE , fname)
  File "/My/work/dir/memory.py", line 185, in __init__
    self.f = h5py.File(fname, 'w', driver='mpio', comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD)
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 270, in __init__
    fapl = make_fapl(driver, libver, **kwds)
  File "/hom/miniconda/envs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 73, in make_fapl
    kwds.setdefault('info', mpi4py.MPI.Info())
NameError: name 'mpi4py' is not defined
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem? I didn't find any answer that could help me online.

Thank you

Comment: I reinstalled my environment and it works now, but i am still interested to know where this problem came from and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [installation documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/build.html#custom-installation) for h5py, it looks like installing a parallelized version of the HDF5 library with MPI support is an option so you might have installed it without that option or misconfigured an environment variable such as `HDF5_MPI=ON`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought installing it with pip will handle it (since mpi4py was already installed).